# Adding NHibernate Filter definition to all the tables dynamically at runtime

Tags: c#, filter, nhibernate

I use mapping by code approach to define the entity mapping. Now I want to configure a same [filter](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/filters.html) on around 200 mapping classes. Is there any approach to add the filter mapping dynamically at run time?

My class-mapping looks similar to the below.

```
public class EntityMap : ClassMapping<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        Table("Entity");
        Filter("filterName", m => m.Condition("FilteredField = filterParamName"));
        // remaining mapping
    }
}
```

Instead of pasting the below filter mapping in all the mapping classes, I would like to map the filters at run time.

```
Filter("filterName", m => m.Condition("FilteredField = :filterParamName"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelMapper` (which should be used somewhere in your code to 'compile' all mappings and supply them to `Configuration`) class contains many After/Before events which allow to modify mappings dynamically. It seems `AfterMapClass` or `BeforeMapClass` should work for you. Something like:

```
var mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.AfterMapClass +=
    (inspector, type, customizer) =>
    {
        customizer.Filter("filterName", m => m.Condition("FilteredField = :filterParamName")); 
    };
```